# Scroll through web images after thumbnail

Tags: php, scroll

I searched, but did not find the answer to this.

I have a website that displays hundreds of images in thumbnail format.  I'm currently using php to display all of the images in thumbnail, then when the thumbnail is clicked upon to display the images in full-size.

What I would like to do is be able to click on a thumbnail and see the resulting full-size image, then at that point be able to scroll both back and forth through the full-size images without going back to the thumbnails.

As an added feature, when viewing the thumbnails, I would like to only load the ones that are currently displayed on the client page...ie - if the client screen resolution supports 20, then load only 20 and wait to load the rest on the client until the user scrolls down. The primary client in this use case is an iphone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a slider jquery plugin

Like

**[Jquery Light Box Plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)**

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the image, it should point to a new PHP file containing the full size image, or even better, load it in a new `<div>` with php you can get the client resolution with [other tools](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1251-php-detect-the-display-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

You actual have two seperate questions. One is to show the thumbs fullsize and be able to click to the next image. Almost every plugin to show images has that options. Personally i use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), but pick anyone you like. To enable the next/prev buttons you need to group the images useing the `rel` tag.

Now to load the images per page, similar to google does it, you need to load it all in by javascript. Below is a setup of how you could do it. This is untested, as I did not have an image gallery at hand.

In the code below I load all images into the array at once, which is not perfect when you have a lot of images (like 1000+). In that case your better of using AJAX to load a new page. But if you have a smaller amount of images, this will be faster.

```
<script>
//simple JS class to store thumn and fullimage url
function MyImage(thumbnail, fullimage, imgtitle) {
  this.thumb = thumbnail;
  this.full = fullimage;
  this.title = imgtitle;
}

//array that holds all the images
var imagesArray = new Array();
var currentImage = 0;

<?php
//use php code to loop trough your images and store them in the array
//query code to fetch images
//each row like $row['thumb'] and $row['full'] and $row['title'];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo "imagesArray.push(new MyImage('".$row['thumb']."', '".$row['full']."', '".$row['title']."'));";
}
?>

//the thumb width is the width of the full container incl. padding
//In this case I want to use 50x50 images and have 10px on the right and at the bottom. Which results in 60x60
var thumbWidth = 60;
var thumbHeight = 60;

var screenWidth = $('body').width();
var screenHeight = $('body').height();

var maxImagesPerRow = Math.round(screenWidth / thumbWidth);
var maxImagesPerCol = Math.round(screenHeight / thumbHeight);
var totalImagesPerPage = maxImagesPerRow * maxImagesPerCol;


//function to load a new page
//assuming you use jquery
function loadNextPage() {
  var start = currentImage;
  var end = currentImage + totalImagesPerPage;
  if (end >= imagesArray.length) {
    end = imagesArray.length - 1;
  }
  if (end<=start)
    return; //last images loaded

  $container = $('#thumbnailContainer'); //save to var for speed
  $page = $('<div></div>'); //use a new container, not on stage, to prevent the dom for reloading everything on each iteration of the loop
  for (start;start<=end;start++) {
    //add a new thumbnail to the page
    $page.append('<div style="margin:0;padding:0 10px 10px 0;"><a class="fancybox" rel="mygallery" href="'+imagesArray[start].full+'" title="'+imagesArray[start].title+'"><img src="'+imagesArray[start].thumb+'" alt="" /></a></div>');
  }
  currentImage = start;

  //when all images are added to the page, add the page to the container.
  $container.append($page);
}

$(function() { 
  //when loading ready, load the first page
  loadNextPage();  
});

//function to check if we need to load a new page
function checkScroll() {
  var fromTop = $('body').scrollTop();
  //page with a 1-based index
  var page = 1 + Math.round(fromTop / screenHeight); 

  var loadedImages = page*totalImagesPerPage;

  if (loadedImages==currentImage)  {
    //we are scrolling the last loaded page
    //load a new page
    loadNextPage();
  }  
}

window.onscroll = checkScroll;

</script>

<body>
    <div id='thumbnailContainer'></div>
</body>
```